# Android - Override custom view's parent's default attribute values

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I have an android custom View called `QuizBar` which is a subclass of `SeekBar`. `SeekBar` sets default values for some of its attributes that are different from the defaults that I want `QuizBar` to have. What is **the best** way to change these defaults? I could mess with the `AttributeSet` passed to the constructor but that would be messy and hard to change. It seems like there would be an easier way to do this.

Comment: What default are you trying to set?

Comment: android:progressBackgroundTint and
android:progressBackgroundTintMode to make the seekbar symetrical

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to just change the default value of the `progressBackgroundTint` and `progressBackgroundTintMode` then you can just call its [setter method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setProgressBackgroundTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)) within your class's constructor and set its default value.

Remember that both setter methods for the above values are only available for 21 and above so make sure you check the version before you set it.